# othello reversi game :how to count number of cells in a 64 cell grid view

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am designing an android game that needs a grid view of 64 cells(8*8). this grid view will allow user to place white and black disc in each cell. i have managed to do that i want to know how do i calculate number of cells occupied by white and black repectively.. any help will be much appreciated

```
OnItemClickListener boardListener = new OnItemClickListener()    {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   //to add toast

                   if (board[position] == 0) {

                   board[position]=playerNo;
                    if (playerNo==1) {
                        playerNo=2;

                    }
                    else{
                        playerNo=1;
                    }
             boardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: learn to isolate view and data model you must, young padawan!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through each cell and check using a for loop. Try to be more specific, the more specific your question is, the more specific (and therefore helpful) your answer can be.

```
public int cellCount(Board board, int playernum) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        if (board[i] == playernum)
            count++;
    return count;
}
```